# Am failing to download torrents

Tags: transmission, deluge, qbittorrent

I recently moved on from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 13.10. I torrented a lot of files but I can't seem to get it work. I tried qBittorrent and the files only stayed at 'stalled'. I tried Deluge but the files won't get past 'downloading 0.00%' and with Transmission... it says 'downloading from 0 of 0 peers'.

Comment: Is whatever port you are using in qBittorrent forwarded through your router? The peer listening port can be found in the settings for your torrent client and you can check if the port is open here: http://www.canyouseeme.org/ You'll need to refer to instructions for your specific router for how to setup port forwarding as they all differ.

Answer (score 3):

After opening your torrent program, open its preferences and check if the port it listens on is open. From transmission:

[image]

From Deluge:

[image]

Do a "test port" and it should show "open". If it shows "closed" your router is not set properly. My router has DD-WRT but all routers probably will show something similar tyo this somewhere:

[image]